# Recycler updates with duplicate values

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I use wipe to delete method to delete a row, When i delete one row from the recycler list view  it duplicates the value just below the one I had deleted.
If I delete "Test 3" from the list
[image]

it shows a duplicate of "Test 4" in 3rd and 4th position

[image]

my whole code used for list creation and deletion, can any one help me with this

```
public class fragmnetPendingAct extends Fragment {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    ArrayList<String> activitynames;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    View view;

    List<modelclasspendingact> modelclasspendingactList = new ArrayList<>();



    public fragmnetPendingAct() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pendingactivity,container,false);

        refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_activitypend);

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewpendingact);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        new ItemTouchHelper(itemtouchHelpercalback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);







        //listen to swipe horizontal
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                // Get new Instance ID token
                FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                mUser.getIdToken(true)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                                    // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                                    getdatafromserver(token);

                                } else {
                                    // Handle error -> task.getException();
                                    Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed second", task.getException());

                                }
                            }
                        });


                refreshitems();
            }
        });







        // Get new Instance ID token
        FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mUser.getIdToken(true)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete lead: "+token);
                            // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                            getdatafromserver(token);

                        } else {
                            // Handle error -> task.getException();
                            Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed second", task.getException());

                        }
                    }
                });




        return v;
    }






    public void getdatafromserver(String token){

        //new code using curl
        String serverurl="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, serverurl,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, "activity list: "+response);


                            JSONObject alldata=response.getJSONObject("payload");

                            JSONArray assetaarray=alldata.getJSONArray("activities");



                            modelclasspendingactList.removeAll(modelclasspendingactList);


                            for(int i=0;i<assetaarray.length();i++)
                            {
                              JSONObject getactivity=assetaarray.getJSONObject(i);
                              String activityid = String.valueOf(getactivity.getInt("id"));
                              String activityname = getactivity.getString("title");
                              String activitydesc = getactivity.getString("description");
                                Log.d(TAG, "activity name: "+activityname);


                                //list crreation
                                modelclasspendingactList.add(new modelclasspendingact(activityname,activitydesc,activityid));
                                pendingactAdapter adapter = new pendingactAdapter(modelclasspendingactList);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                            }




                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                error.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        ){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> headers=new HashMap<String,String>();
                headers.put("Accept","*/*");
                headers.put("Cache-Control","no-cache");
                headers.put("cache-control","no-cache");
                headers.put("token",token);

                return headers;
            }
        };
        singletonclasshttp.getInstance(getActivity()).addtorequestque(jsonObjectRequest);



    }


    private void refreshitems()
    {

        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }

    //swipe function
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemtouchHelpercalback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onSwiped: "+modelclasspendingactList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPendid());
            Log.d(TAG, "onSwiped: position "+viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

            String activeid = modelclasspendingactList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPendid();


            // Get new Instance ID token
            FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            mUser.getIdToken(true)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                                //send token and activity id to update function
                                markascompleted(activeid,token);


                            } else {
                                // Handle error -> task.getException();
                                Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed second", task.getException());

                            }
                        }
                    });

            Log.d(TAG, "onSwiped: position "+viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            Log.d(TAG, "onSwiped: first list size "+modelclasspendingactList.size());


            pendingactAdapter adapter = new pendingactAdapter(modelclasspendingactList);
            modelclasspendingactList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            recyclerView.removeViewAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
//            adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), modelclasspendingactList.size());
//            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d(TAG, "onSwiped: list size "+modelclasspendingactList.size());



//            pendingactAdapter adapter = new pendingactAdapter(modelclasspendingactList);
//            modelclasspendingactList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
//            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());


        }
    };





    private void markascompleted(String activeid,String token)
    {
        //send data to server
        //curl function

        String serverurl="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new ArrayMap<>();
        jsonParams.put("id", activeid);
        jsonParams.put("activityStatus", "COMPLETED");
        jsonParams.put("targetEmployeeId", "1001");
        jsonParams.put("score", "1");



        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, serverurl,new JSONObject(jsonParams),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "response: "+response);


                        try {
                            if (response.optBoolean("success")==true)
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Not Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Not Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Not Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ){

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> headers=new HashMap<String,String>();
                headers.put("Accept","*/*");
                headers.put("Cache-Control","no-cache");
                headers.put("Connection","keep-alive");
                headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                headers.put("cache-control","no-cache");
                headers.put("token",token);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        singletonclasshttp.getInstance(getActivity()).addtorequestque(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

}
```

Comment: notifyItemRemoved after this you don't need notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @AnasMehar Still the problem exists

Comment: can check your adapter list list.size() after notifyDataSetChanged using debugging.

Comment: @AlvinJohnNiravukalayil Don't call `notifyItemRangeChanged()`

Comment: @AnasMehar initially it is 6 and when delete its 5

Comment: @ZohaibAmir this too doesn't work

Comment: @AlvinJohnNiravukalayil where is this code you pasted and where is your list object?

Comment: @AlvinJohnNiravukalayil Can you Show the Adapter and the actual code where you call these functions?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir please check the question, I had updated it.

Comment: @AlvinJohnNiravukalayil just as I thought, found the problem, posting answer in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll explain why you get this behavior, then we'll get to solution.
In this code:

**Problem #1:**

```
pendingactAdapter adapter = new pendingactAdapter(modelclasspendingactList);
```

You are creating an adapter and pass it your *current* data. Note that the adapter will have its own copy of the list you passed in constructor.

```
modelclasspendingactList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

This list that you are removing Item from is **different** from the one you just sent in Adapter, so the Adapter **still has old list**.
Then you call removed and adapter tries to update values but your removed item is still in the list that adapter has.

**Solution**:
Create A Function/Method in Adapter that removes the item **from the list in adapter**.

**Problem #2 with Solution:**
You are creating a new Adapter instance/object every time a view is swiped, it is unnecessary. Create the Adapter in class instead of function and instantiate it in onCreateView().

Comment: Thanks a ton bro. You saved me.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.

First, the `removeViewAt` is a function of `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`.  I imagine you meant to say `recyclerView.LayoutManager.removeViewAt`.

Second, the call to `removeViewAt` should not be necessary as `RecyclerView` does this automatically when `notifyItemRemoved` is called correctly.

Third, you do not need to re-bind the entire list when removing an item.  You can remove the `notifyItemRangeChanged`.

Fourth, you do not need to invalidate the entire adapter when removing an item either.  You can remove `notifyDataSetChanged`.  In fact, this function should only be used as a last resort.

Initializing your `RecyclerView`:

```
pendingactAdapter adapter = new pendingactAdapter(modelclasspendingactList);
RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
recyclerView.adapter = adapter;
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

So your removal sequence should be

```
 modelclasspendingactList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
 adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

Comment: but when i use this code it deletes but it doesn't align, there is a gap in the row deleted.

Comment: This seems like an issue with the layout manager.  Update your question with code that shows how you are initializing your recycler view.  I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: I had updated my question with whole code. I got the solution, thank you for your answers.